# databricks secrets in init scripts

Tags: databricks, datadog

In order to use Datadog, I use an init script according to [databricks datatdog integration](https://docs.datadoghq.com/integrations/databricks/?tab=driveronly).

Hence I fill spark environment variables as on the attached picture. [image: spark env vars]

It is working when I fill in the datadog key not encrypted but as soon as I fill it with `{{secrets/datadog/api_key}}`, it is not working.

Comment: what does it mean "not working" what value do you get inside the init script? Does the cluster owner have permissions to access this secret?

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to determine the actual issue based on the way your question is currently worded. Based on the limited information provided, I would check the following:

1. Verify the secret exists in the location provided.
2. Is {{secret/datadog/api_key}} an actual secret scope?
3. Does your Databricks instance have access to the secret scope?